# Проблемы с onTouch

Tags: android, прокрутка, ontouchlistener

Реализовую такую вещь. При касании экрана на нем добавляется `TextView`, в дальнейшем, если дотронутся до `TextView`, он будет перемещается за пальцем. Для этого реализовал такой обработчик

```
OnTouchListener t = new OnTouchListener(){
                public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    int x = Math.round(event.getX());
                    int y = Math.round(event.getY());

                    b.setText(x +"  " +y);

                    switch(event.getAction()){
                        case  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            if(v instanceof AbsoluteLayout){
                            add(x,y,this);}
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                            if(v instanceof TextView){
                                v.setX(x);
                                v.setY(y);
                            }

                            break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }
        };
```

Этот обработчик присваюеться `Layout` и созданным `TextView`. Вроде все работает, но проблема в том, что при скроле `TextView` он странно дергается вверх вниз, хотя за пальцем передвигается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Т.е. у вас высота текста больше высоты TextView? Если да, то попробуйте обернуть его в ScrollView и проставить высоту в WrapContent

Comment: Я думаю проблема в другом. Дело в том что, так как обработчик присвоен и слою и TextVieq одновременно он присылает координаты касания то слоя, то внутри TextView, отсюда и сдвиги

Comment: Очевидно, ИМХО, что в наличии конфликт скрола и вашего слушателя. Т.к. скрол TextView реализован хуже, чем у ScrollView, то это может помочь. Вообще скролить текст силами textView - плохая идея.